# Exchanging object with sockets

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

I am trying to write a simple interaction between a client and a server in Java by using sockets.

### Server

```
public class MyServer
{
  private static final int SPORT = 4444;
  ServerSocket server;
  Socket client;
  ObjectInputStream is;
  ObjectOutputStream os;


  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  public MyServer() {
    try
    {
      server = new ServerSocket(SPORT);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    listenAndReply();
  }


  public void listenAndReply()
  {
    System.out.println("Server running.");
    System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
    try
    {
      client = server.accept();

      System.out.println("Connection accepted. \n");

      is = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
      os = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

      while(! client.isClosed()) {

        Object o = is.readObject();

        // ... process object ...

      }
    }
    catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


  public void sendCommand(Command c) {
    try
    {
      os.reset();
      os.writeObject(c);
      os.flush();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

### Client

```
public class MyClient implements ChatClient
{
  private static final int SPORT    = 4444;
  private static final String SHOST = "127.0.0.1";
  Socket socket;
  ObjectInputStream is = null;
  ObjectOutputStream os = null;


  public MyClient() {
    try
    {
      socket = new Socket(SHOST, SPORT);
      os = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      is = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
      System.out.println("Client socket created.");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


  @Override
  public Command receive()
  {
    try
    {
      Object o = is.readObject();

      if(o instanceof Command) {
        System.out.println("Received command: " + o.getClass().getSimpleName());
        return (Command) o;
      }
    }
    catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
  }


public void sendCommand(Command c) {
    System.out.println("Client sending command " + c.getClass().getSimpleName());

    try
    {
      os.reset();
      os.writeObject(c);
      os.flush();
      System.out.println("Command sent. \n");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Can you see something wrong? The problem is that if I try to exchange multiple objects I get

java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00

## EDIT - SOLVED

In the end I managed to solve the problem: as Pshemo suspected, the problem was not in this code but in another class where there was another call to the receive method, and this was obviously causing strange behaviours. Now I will have to re-think a bit about the structure, but at least the socket communication seems fine.

Comment: What is the purpose of `os.reset();` in `sendCommand`?

Comment: It should reset the stream to make it look like a newly-opened one, as I read in another question. Anyway leaving it out does not change the outcome.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Can you create and post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (short but full code reproducing your problem)?

Comment: Actually this is only a little part of a bigger project. I thought I was just making some silly mistakes with the object streams, so I tried to cut everything else and I posted just the code which is related to object exchanging

Comment: Yes, I realise that but creating SSCCE has many advantages: (1) it helps you narrow problem (2) which makes answering easier (3) and it helps future readers easier test if they are facing similar problem. So I would advise creating it anyway because of point 1 (I often find problems in my code while creating SSCCE so it is really worth spending fair amount of time in creating it).

Comment: I tried to write a very simple string ping-pong using sockets and it works perfectly. I used the exact same approach described above, so I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: This may mean that problem is not in part you are showing us (so we are going back to point 1 - narrowing the real problem). Like I said, from code you posted I also wasn't able to reproduce your problem. Maybe it is not what this code does, but how it is used is wrong?

Comment: It is possible. The fact is we have to extend/complete the code which was given to us by a professor... I will try to ask him

Answer (score -1):

In the server class you are trying to get input and output from client but in your client class you set up tour client socket as socket instead of client. You're trying to pull info through a class instead of a socket so I'm going to guess that's your problem. Correct me if I'm wrong

```
public class MyServer{

private static final int SPORT = 4444;



/**
* Constructor
*/
public MyServer() {
try
{
  ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(SPORT);
}
catch (IOException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}

listenAndReply();
}


public void listenAndReply(){

System.out.println("Server running.");
System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
try
{
  socket = server.accept();

  System.out.println("Connection accepted. \n");

  InputStream is = new InputStream(socket.getInputStream()); //changed from client.getInputStream() because in your client class you have setup your client socket to be named socket instead of client.
  OutputStream os = new OutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); //changed from client.getOutputStream() since your client class has a differently named client socket, your server can’t get information from it by calling client.get

  while( !socket.isClosed()) {

    Object o = is.readObject();

    // ... process object ...

  }
}
catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: What does '... but in your client class you set up tour client socket as socket instead of client' mean? Thank you

Comment: In you client class you set up your client socket as socket socket = new socket but in your server class your in and out streams come from client.get.. See. Your trying to pull from a socket name that isn't instantiated in ur client

Comment: Oh yes, just a typo... Anyway I still don't get the point: in the server class, client is declared as a Socket object, and in the client class I try to connect to the server via a Socket object named 'socket'. Am I missing something about your answer?

Comment: Exactly, your server is looking for client.getinput and output when it should be looking for socket.getinput/output because that's the way you set up your client

Comment: socket is not a member of the server class, so how is it supposed to be found? The name of the socket is 'client' and this is what I used to get the streams. Anyway, I tried as you say but I obviously obtain 'socket cannot be resolved'.

Comment: Hold on let me get to a cup instead of tablet

Comment: updated my answer to show code changes that im talking about in your server class

Comment: It does not matter what I did in the client class. The server class does not know any object called 'socket', so I get 'socket cannot be resolved'. The name of the object in the server class is 'client' and I have to use that one.

Comment: ur making a point just let me look at the code a while and ill get back

Comment: regardless, your client server inputstream comes from "clientsocket".getInputStream() and your output comes from "clientsocket".getoutputstream(). that means that "clientsocket" has to match whatever you are calling your client. you cant call the client "socket" and try to get info from "client" it doesnt work that way. i dont know why you are instantiating a client name in your server class anyway, that probably has alot to do with your problems. when they connect over the net it just isnt going to work if they arnt named correctly and its going to time out because client doesnt exist

Comment: I can assure you that the connection does work! I can exchange objects correctly, but only the first time, then I start having exceptions. This is the reason why I tell you that I suspect the problem is in the object streams and not in the connection

Comment: well, i withdraw my argument. as far as i can see thats the only thing i see wrong. but dont assume that its not a problem with the connection, your whole progrm depends on reliable connection. btw where are you closing your sockets, i dont see it but i do see where you're depending on the connection being open to pass objects in your while loop, if you have the close argument set incorrectly then it will close connection immediatly after the first exchange and and youll start getting exceptions

Comment: To avoid this kind of problem I just don't close the sockets, at least for the moment